# spring security with solr database

Tags: solr, spring-security

By client requirements, instead of using postgres database, we will be using solr for the security in the application.

So far i haven't found anything in google, how i can achieve this without doing it 'by hand'?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way go through the [Spring Data Solr's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/) first. That gives a brief overview, how to integrate Solr with Spring Data. After that, it should be very similar, how you integrate Spring Security with Postgres.